# Typescript Chain Constants with a Negative function

Tags: typescript, chain

I am working in Typescript 2.8.1 and want to group my constants into a common file, similar to an include file in other languages.  While this is straight forward, I am trying to chain some methods to work with the values and cannot seem to get it to work.

EDIT: Need a default return for simplicity and have correcte my initial problem of not returning the object.

For instance, I have the numbers 1 to 10 as defined constants:

```
export enum CONSTANTS {
    ONE = 1, TWO, ... TEN
}
```

I want to be able to use these in code, such as `CONSTANTS.FIVE` for the number 5, but also be able to possibly do a `CONSTANTS.NEGATIVE.FIVE` to get -5.

I am trying to use chained methods, but it appears that I need to then define the original enumerations as individual methods that return a value.

```
export class CONSTANTS {
    private Value_:number;

    public constructor() {
        this.Value_ = 0;
    }
    public ONE() {
        this.Value_ = 1;
        return this;
    }
    public TWO() {
        this.Value_ = 2;
        return this;
    }
    public NEGATIVE() {
        this.Value_ = this.Value_ * -1;
        return this;
    }
    public GetValue() {
        return this.Value_;    // This is the function I want to default to at the end
}

value = new CONSTANTS().ONE().NEGATIVE();        // Trying for -1
```

Leaving off the GetValue(); returns the object.

Comment: That's because each method is returning value rather than a reference to the object containing the next method.

Comment: This is some variation of a fluent builder pattern... When you make such things, you usually return `this` and then call some `.Build` at the end of the chain. Right now it's failing because `.NEGATIVE` is defined for your `CONSTANTS`, but you are trying to call it on a `number`.

Comment: Thanks.  Just noticed what I did wrong there.  If you want to move this to an answer I can accept it.  I am also just quickly looking to get the value by default, so I could end with NEGATIVE() and have the value returned without needing another function. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You know, it would be much more straight forward to use your CONSTANTS with the negative unary operator ( `-CONSTANTS.FIVE`)

Comment: That works for legibility for this.  I am trying to work with different data types and functions, such as .NOT(), or maybe something else.  Trying to achieve a similar results to the test libraries that can chain things together.  to.equal(), not.to.equal(), and then be able to answer things such as yesterday() to subtract a day, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, and to simplify your code you could use the negative unary operator:

```
export enum CONSTANTS {
    ONE = 1, TWO = 2, ... TEN
}

//**//

console.log(-CONSTANTS.TWO)
```